# How to interpret thresholds of ROC AUC Curves for Decision Trees?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, roc, auc

When using a discrete classifier like decision tree, we get a single point (FPR, TPR) by through the confusion matrix, now when I try to plot ROC AUC curve, I get thresholds :

```
roc_curve(y_test,mod.predict(X_test))
```

Output :

```
(array([  0.00000000e+00,   5.92624518e-04,   1.00000000e+00]),
 array([ 0.        ,  0.11766772,  1.        ]),
 array([ 2.,  1.,  0.]))
```

**threshold = [2.,1.,0.,]**

I am unable to interpret these thresholds, how do I interpret them to find TPR and FPR?

Comment: Please update your question to include which package(s) you are using.  IE where is roc_curve from?

Answer (score 2):

Look here [sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)

The first array of your roc_curve return is fpr, the second is tpr and the thirs is threshold

when you plot fpr (X) on tpr (Y) for each threshold yo get the [ROC curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py)